# aws SDK 3, PHP, runInstance does not create the supplied Tags

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

```
        $options = array(
            'UserData' => base64_encode('test'),
            'SecurityGroupIds' => [AWS_REGIONS[$region]['security_group']],  
            'InstanceType' => AWS_REGIONS[$region]['instance_type'],
            'ImageId' => AWS_REGIONS[$region]['ami'],
            'MaxCount' => $to_launch,
            'MinCount' => 1,
            //'EbsOptimized' => true,
            'SubnetId' => AWS_REGIONS[$region]['subnet_id'],
            'Tags' => [['Key' => 'task', 'Value' => $task],['Key' => 'Name', 'Value' => $task]],
            'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior' => 'terminate'
        );
        $response = $client->runInstances($options);
```

I am using the "latest" Ec2Client

It launches fine but the Tags are completely ignored.
I suspect an error within the EC2 API but I am not that experienced.
Maybe someone with experience can help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Ec2Client::runInstances` does not have tags option
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2015-10-01.html#runinstances

You would need to make a separate call to tag newly created instance(s) using `Ec2Client::createTags`:

```
$result = $client->createTags(array(
    'DryRun' => true || false,
    // Resources is required
    'Resources' => array('string', ... ),
    // Tags is required
    'Tags' => array(
        array(
            'Key' => 'string',
            'Value' => 'string',
        ),
        // ... repeated
    ),
));
```

Read more here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2015-10-01.html#createtags

Comment: You are right, I don't know where I was reading about that. I guess I was in a wrong page of the manual.